# Probability of getting a desired outcome

Tags: probability

I constructed problem I am not quite sure about the solution:

### The problem

A machine can give me stuff. There are 3 possible choices:

1. I get nothing with $p=0.5$
2. I get my desired stuff with $p=0.001$
3. I get junk I don't need with $p=0.499$

The machine does this up to 7 times. BUT if the machine gives me something in its first 6 give-aways (all of the first 6) it will automatically cancel its 7th give-away and set it 'nothing'. Edit clarification: with something I mean desired stuff or junk but not nothing. Edit clarification 2: The 7th trial is only set to nothing if all of the first 6 trials are not equal to 'nothing'.

### Question

What is the propability that I get my desired stuff?

### My guess

My guess is that we can model it with a multinomial distribution. So the space of all events looks like this (we always have at least one 'nothing' outcome in our space, because of the working of the machine.)

$\Omega := \{(\omega_1,...,\omega_7) : \exists i \in \{1,...,7\} : \omega_i = nothing \wedge w_k \in \{nothing, desired, junk\}\forall  k\in\{1,..,7\} \setminus \{i\}\}$

Let $A$ be the event "I get exactly one desired thing from the machine".

My guess:
$P(A) = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^6\frac{7!}{i!1!(6-i)!}p_{nothing}^i\cdot p_{desired}\cdot p_{junk}^{6-i}$

I add up all the propabilities that give me one desired stuff. We start with $i=1$ because we have always at least one 'nothing' in our $w_i$. Is this correct or am I missing something?

### Alternative 'solution'

I also started to solve this with conditional propability which gives me a different solution.

I looked at 2 conditions

$B_1 = \{(\omega_1,...,\omega_7) : \omega_i \neq nothing \forall i \in \{1,..,6\}  \}$ meaning that $w_7=nothing$.

$B_2 = \{(\omega_1,...,\omega_7) : \exists i \in \{1,...,6\} : \omega_i = nothing \wedge w_k \in \{nothing, desired, junk\}\forall  k\in\{1,..,7\} \setminus \{i\} \}$

But this yields a different solution I will write more, would be happy to see if multinomial guess is correct.

Comment: There are two routes to success.  Either you get what you want within the first $6$ trials or you get nothing six times in a row and then you get what you want.  The two probabilities are easy to calculate.

Comment: I am note sure I can also have the case: I don't get it in the first 6 trials but I get for example (junk, nothing, nothing, nothing, junk, junk, desired)

Comment: No...your rules state (or at least appear to state) that if you get something, even junk, at any point along the first six trials then the seventh trial is set to nothing.

Comment: Sorry this is indeed very unclear, how I wrote this. The machine only sets its 7th trial to nothing only if the first six trials (all of them) were always 'not nothing' i.e. the desired thing occured or junk occured in all the first 6 trials. If at least one of the first 6 trials is set to 'nothing' then a 7th trial will occur. Really sorry for that my bad.

Comment: Ok, so then you have the probability to succeed in the first seven trials but you have to subtract the probability of the path in which you get junk six times in a row followed by success in trial seven.  Still easy.

Comment: Thank you so the probability is $P(A) = \binom{7}{1}\cdot 0.001\cdot (1-0.001)^6 - 0.499^6 \cdot0.001$

Comment: No.  it's still ok if you succeed more than once .  Thus the answer is $1-(1-p_{\text{desired}})^7 - p_{\text {junk}}^6p_{\text {desired}}$.

Comment: Ok thank you. Originally I wanted to answer the question "what is the probability to get exactly one desired outcome". But again, this is notstated in my initial post (forgot it...).